# MS C# tutorial code doesn't work in VS2013?

Tags: c#

I'm following through Microsoft's [C# tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/types-variables) to eventually learn .net, I've put this code into my VS 2013 and for some reason the output shows that "$" was an unexpected character. Throughout the tutorial it hasn't mentioned `using` anything side from System,

From MS

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var name = "Steve"; // use your name here
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
    }
}
```

What I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var name = "John";
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}!");
        }
    }
}
```

VS2013 says it was expecting a ')' in the part of the line where its written `($"Hello {name}!");`

If I remove the $ it outputs the sentence as it's written *Hello {name}!*

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (string literals starting with `$"`) were introduced in C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015).

Note that you can download and use the free Community Edition of Visual Studio 2015, if you are student, an open-source developer or and individual developer. [Visual Studio 2017 is Launching on March 7 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_developer_switzerland_news/2017/02/17/visual-studio-2017-is-launching-on-march-7/) and also has a free Community Edition and supports [C#7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7) (introducing tuples with the new tuple syntax, pattern matching and much more).

Official [Visual Studio Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) site.

Comment: Oh I just need to update okay, awesome thank you Olivier!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it the old way (pre c# 6.0).

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hello {0}", name));
```

Comment: Interesting. So does the introduction of interpolated strings make it simpler and more flexible?